# On the integral closure of Noetherian local domain in a finite extension field of the fraction field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, extension-field, integral-extensions, formal-completions

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local domain such that the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion of $R$ is also an integral domain. Let $K$ be the fraction field of $R$ . Let $L$ be a finite extension field of $K$. 
Let $\overline R_L$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$.

Under what conditions on $R$ or $L$ can we say that $\overline R_L$ is also local (I'm especially interested when $L=K$) ? When can we say $\overline R_L$  is also Noetherian ?

I know $\overline R_L$ is a Krull domain by Mori-Nagata theorem and that if $R$ has dimension $1$ , then $\overline R_L$ is Noetherian.

Apart from that I don't know anything else.

Please help.

Comment: A question like `under what conditions' is difficult, except that it is rare. Even when $R$ is a 1-dimensional and regular, the integral closure in a finite extension is seldom local.

Comment: @Mohan: I guess $L=K$ would be easier to handle ?

Comment: If $L=K$, then $\overline{R}$ is a Noetherian local domain. I cannot find an exact reference but Ch 4 of the book of Swanson-Huneke contains relevant materials (the book is available for free from the webpage of Irena Swanson). In particular, look at Corollary 4.6.2 and Theorem 4.3.4.

Comment: @Youngsu: I think that is only true when $R$ has dimension at most $2$. Nagata gave some counterexamples in dimension $3$

Comment: Hi @user521337, can you give me more information about Nagata's example?